# Redux Framework not working when used in plugin

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I'm going to use redux framework for my plugin options, it is showing in admin panel and i can save the settings,

I used the sample config file for option panel,

So the problem is that i m not getting the option values by printing the global `opt_name` variable.

If I add the redux framework config file to theme functions.php then it worked, but not working in plugin,

Please help me if some one know about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Lead dev of Redux here.

The issue is Redux hasn't had a chance to run yet!

If you're using the new Redux API just run: Redux::init('opt_name') and it will suddenly work.  :)

Comment: Another option is to run your config, and then delay the rest of your plugin until plugins_loaded priority 2.  ;)

Comment: Hi, Dovy
Thanks you your reply,

 I put Redux::init('opt_name') in my initSettings function but it did not work, By the way what do you mean by New Redux API? i m using the latest redux plugin,

Also can you please explain the 2nd option little more, how to run config and delay plugin until plugin_loaded priority 2,

i did this add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'initSettings' ), 2 );

but this did not work too.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run Redux in plugin, just run :

`Redux::init("opt_name"); // opt_name is your opt_name`

before using it